# How to use AppCMD to test and see if a website exists in IIS7 using the Site's Name?

Tags: appcmd

I would like to add new bindings to a site using appcmd but I need to see if it exists first. How can I do so using AppCMD?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 15):

You can create a batch file with the following code :

```
@ECHO OFF

SET appcmd=CALL %WINDIR%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd

%appcmd% list site /name:"Default Web Site"
IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" EQU "0" (
    ECHO EXISTS
    REM Add your bindings here
) ELSE (
    ECHO NOT EXISTS
)
```

Comment: This works for the top level node, but what about a site located under "Default Web Site"?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the PowerShell way:

```
$exists = (&$appcmd list apppool /name:'MyApplicationPool') -ne $null

if ($exists -eq $false)
{
    Write-Host 'App Pool does not exist'
}
else
{
    Write-Host 'App Pool exists'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the site.name and do that in one line with the command line : `"%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe" list apps /path:"/PORTALSiteName" /site.name:"Default Web Site" && ECHO EXISTS`